# Sharing Custom Open Graph Objects using Facebook's JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

I'm currently trying to use the `share_open_graph` method of `FB.ui` of Facebook's JavaScript SDK.

My call is nested in the callback for a `FB.api` request where I successfully POST an Open Graph object to their API and looks like so:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'NAMESPACE:share',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        object: URL
    })
}, function(response) {
    console.log('shareDialog', response);
});
```

Where `NAMESPACE` is my application namespace, `share` is a custom action I've created in my application settings, and `URL` matches the URL of the API call exactly.

I am getting the following error inside the dialog, not as a console error:

> At least one reference object must be specified.

Instead of `object` as a key, I've also tried `NAMESPACE:CUSTOM_OBJECT_TYPE`, and `CUSTOM_OBJECT_TYPE`. In the API response, I have access to the object ID that was POSTed. I have also tried replacing `URL` with this value for all of the stated key options with no success.

[Facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) is lacking any other help, any one else have clues? Thanks!

EDIT: Given some [newly found documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.2#params) I've revised my example code to:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'NAMESPACE:share',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        CUSTOM_OBJECT_TYPE: OBJECT_ID
    })
}, function(response) {
    console.log('shareDialog', response);
});
```

Which unfortunately still throws the same exact error but I think I'm getting more on the right track. I've also tried `'NAMESPACE:CUSTOM_OBJECT_TYPE'` in place of `CUSTOM_OBJECT_TYPE` with no success

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: No unfortunately I haven't